# Combinación de 2 tablas

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio, android-volley

Necesito realizar una validación de 2 tablas, es decir, al insertar datos a una tabla, hago otra inserción a otra tabla, de una imagen con la ruta y la imagen
Pero cuando necesito consultar los datos de ambas tablas para realizar la validación tengo errores...
Como puedo realizar la validación

Comment: Añade más información del error que te muestra

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, recuerda realizar tus preguntas en base al documento [ask] para que obtengas la ayuda requerida en el sitio, te sugerimos editar tu pregunta. No olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos!